# Spacemacs escape key needs delay to work

Tags: tmux, evil-mode

I have clean install of [spacemacs](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs). When I press escape to enter normal mode then immediately press `u` it will uppercase a word. If I wait a second, it will undo last action.

I'm assuming this is `evil-mode` or `emacs` key-chord feature in action. How can I change that behavior?

Comment: This might be more appropriate for http://emacs.stackexchange.com/ , the evil mailing list (implementations-list@lists.ourproject.org), or spacemacs bug tracker. Since this seems to be a spacemacs bug the bug tracker would be the best.

Comment: I'm trying to figure this out too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Spacemacs, particularly the `develop` branch should just work right out of box without the delay. However, I have found that this delay happens when I am running `emacs` inside of `tmux`. You should see if you are trying to run this inside `tmux` or `screen`, and if you are, see if this problem happens when you run `emacs` directly inside a terminal, without a terminal multiplexer.

If `tmux` is your problem, you can fix this with:

```
set -s escape-time 0
```

You'll have to find the equivalent in `screen` if that is what is happening.

See: https://bitbucket.org/lyro/evil/issue/69/delay-between-esc-or-c-and-modeswitch

Comment: "Consequences of 'escape-time 0' tmux setting?": http://superuser.com/q/942677/215067

Answer (score 2):

Zeroing out my delay as Ho-Sheng Hsiao [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31196704/684619) has served me well, but as Wesley Baugh [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30615613/spacemacs-escape-key-needs-delay-to-work/31196704#comment65809470_31196704), that has the consequence of preventing the use of ALT-key modifiers in your editors.

The Emacs-evil FAQ [addresses the problem](https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil#problems-with-the-escape-key-in-terminal-mode), but not very succinctly, and without a concrete recommendation.

The Neovim FAQ has a more succinct [explanation, and a specific recommendation](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/FAQ#esc-in-tmux-or-gnu-screen-is-delayed):

```
set-option -sg escape-time 10  # millisecond delay
```